# a symmetrical die is thrown, then a coin is thrown as many times as the die indicates .

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

---

Exercices :

a symmetrical die is thrown, then a coin is thrown as many times as the die indicates points.

let $X$ be the number of
Tails obtained .

Determine $E(X)$

---

*My attempts :*

First it's clearly that : $$X(\Omega)=\left(1;2;3;4;5;6 \right)$$

Now I need calculs $P(X=1)$ so number of die is $1$ So we thrown the coin $1$-time
So :
$$P(X=1)=\frac{1}{6}×\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{12}$$
Also :
$$P(X=2)=\frac{1}{6}×\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}×\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$$
Is my work correct !!

I need to se more ideas and excellent way

- Edit :

Any solution( answer)!!

---

Thanks

Comment: What are "piles"?  In standard English (at least, American English), a coin can come up either Heads or Tails.  Did you mean one of those?

Comment: If you did mean one of those outcomes, then your computations are wrong.  You could have $X=1$ with *any* of the possible die throws.  Even if you get a $6$ with the die you could get $1$ Heads and $5$ Tails, say.

Comment: As a Hint:  convince yourself that you don't need to think about all the possible outcomes of the coin toss for a given throw of the die.  It's enough to assume that you get the expected value (which is easily computed).

Comment: Sorry I fixe it , just wrong typo " piles " is a word in franchise mean back .

Comment: I looked it up...even in English "piles" used to mean the back of a coin, though that is a very old use.  Anyway, I figured you meant either Heads or Tails.

Comment: Yes sir ,,, if you don't have à problems can you please explain to me your idea?

Comment: I did explain my idea.  For each throw of the die compute the expected number of Tails you'll get.  Then all you have to do is to average those.

Comment: Keywords:  "The Law of Iterated Expectation", "The Law of Total Expectation", or "The Tower Rule".

Comment: @GrahamKemp Can you put  a solution?
Because I'm mentally confused!!

Comment: If you flip a coin $n$ times, the expected number of tails is $n/2$. If you instead flip a coin $N$ times where $N$ is random, it turns out that the expected number of tails is $E[N/2]$. This can be formalized by the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: @angryavian Oh, my thoughts are confused? Is my idea are correct!!

Answer (score 1):

You are somehow on the right track, but your equations are wrong. Let $D$ be the result of the die throw. Then you have actually computed
$$
\newcommand{\E}{\Bbb E}\newcommand{\P}{\Bbb P}
E(X\mid D=1) P(D=1) =\frac{1}{12},$$$$E(X\mid D=2)P(D=2)=\frac16,
$$
and so on. If you sum all these, you get the answer by the law of total expectation:
$$
E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^6E(X\mid D=i)P(D=i).
$$
We can also get away with even less calculation, because the above is equal to
$$
\sum_i \frac i2P(D=i)
= \frac{E(D)}{2}. 
$$
I hope you’ll do your best to understand everything that’s going on here, because it’s quite instructive for similar problems.

---

By the way, if you want to directly compute $P(X=1)$ for example, it’s much more messy:
$$
P(X=1)=\sum_iP(X=1\mid D=i)P(D=i)
$$$$
=\frac12\cdot\frac16 + \frac24\cdot\frac16+\frac38\cdot\frac16+\ldots .
$$
And it only gets worse with higher values than $1$ - you’d have to use binomial coefficients all over the place.

Comment: thank you very much sir!